# showing more then one kml on load in google maps api

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I am trying to show more than one kml at load with a Google Maps API. What is the best way to go about this? Right now it only shows the first kml.

Here is my script.
Thanks for looking.

```
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&signed_in=true"></script>
    <script>
function initialize() {
var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-105.467, 39.973);
    var mapOptions = {
      zoom: 10,
      center: myLatlng,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE
    };

  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);

  var sitesLayer = new google.maps.KmlLayer({
    url: 'https://example.com/kml-kmz-files/basins.kml'
  });
  sitesLayer.setMap(map);

  var basinLayer = new google.maps.KmlLayer({
    url: 'https://example.com/kml-kmz-files/boundries.kml'
  });
  basinLayer.setMap(map);
}


google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

    </script>
```

Comment: There's nothing wrong with your approach. Something else must be amiss. Try checking the layers statuses with `sitesLayer.getStatus()` and `basinLayer.getStatus()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually all layers will be drawn(as long as you didn't exceed any limits), but the API may only set the viewport to contain the features of a single layer(it depends on the loading-order which layer it will be).

To set the viewport so that it contains the features of each layer you must set the `preserveViewport`-property of the layers to `true` and handle the setting of the map-viewport on your own.

Sample-implementation:

```js
function initialize() {
var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(0,0);
    var mapOptions = {
      zoom: 18,
      center: myLatlng
    };

  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), mapOptions);

  loadKml=function(opts,map){
     var layer=new google.maps.KmlLayer();
     opts.preserveViewport=true;
     if(map){opts.map=map;}
     
     google.maps.event.addListener(layer,'defaultviewport_changed',function(){
         var map=this.getMap(),
             bounds=map.get('kmlBounds')||this.getDefaultViewport();
         
         bounds.union(this.getDefaultViewport());
         map.set('kmlBounds',bounds);
         map.fitBounds(bounds); 
     });
     layer.setOptions(opts);
     return layer; 
  }
  //blue pins
  var sitesLayer = loadKml({
    url: 'https://www.google.com/maps/d/kml?mid=z_0vvigsiMo4.kV0iI47miw1A',
    map:map
  });
  //red star
  var basinLayer = loadKml({
    url: 'https://www.google.com/maps/d/kml?mid=z4jtZiEBVczE.kp_M0KHEIung'
  },map);
  
}


google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

```css
html,body,#map{height:100%;margin:0;padding:0}
```

```html
 <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3"></script>
<div id="map"></div>
```